# How to delete a local file after uploading it to Google Drive?

Tags: python

I need a python function that uploads a file to Google Drive and then deletes it from the file system. When trying to use the following code, I get an error when trying to delete the file:

```
def upload():
    file_metadata = {
        'name': 'thankyou.jpg',
        'mimeType': 'image/jpeg'}
    media = MediaFileUpload('thankyou.jpg')
    myfile = drive_service.files().create(body=file_metadata, media_body=media, fields='id').execute()
    os.remove('thankyou.jpg')
```

The upload completes successfully, but I can't delete the file locally after the upload.
The error I get is:

```
PermissionError: [WinError 32] The process cannot access the file 
because it is being used by another process: 'thankyou.jpg'
```

what should I do in order for the file to be deleted?

Comment: As the error is saying, the file is still in use. Is the google drive SDK uploading the file asynchronously, thus, you try to delete it while it is still uploading?

Comment: @user8181134 As far as I know, it is uploading synchronously, since in order to make it asynchronous I would have to add in the meta data "resumable=true". Since I see in Google Drive that the upload is complete, I don't think that's the case. Do you have a suggestion how I can verify it?

Comment: I don't have experience with Google Drive SDK, so I can't answer anything specific to that. Maybe it's still open in another program, like the Windows photo app?

Comment: @user8181134 I'm pretty sure it's specifically related to the MediaFileUpload object which is part of the Google Drive SDK. The file is not open anywhere else (tried with several different files), and when the Python program terminates, I can manually delete it, which wouldn't be possible if another program was involved.

Answer (score 2):

I just ran into this myself in Windows 10, and finally came up with this solution: set the variable used to store your MediaFileUpload object to None:

```
    media = MediaFileUpload(folder+file.name, resumable=True)
logging.info("{} - {} {}MB uploading...".format(datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M:%S"), file.name, file_size))
try:
    service.files().create(body=file_metadata, media_body=media, fields='id').execute()
    logging.info(datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M:%S")+" - "+file.name+" uploaded")
    media = None
except Exception as err:
    logging.warning(datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M:%S")+" - "+file.name+" failed to upload:\nType: {}".format(type(err)))

try:
    os.remove(folder+file.name)
    logging.info(datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M:%S")+" - "+file.name+" deleted.")
except PermissionError as err:
    logging.error("{} - Failed to delete local file. Looks like a permision error: {}".format(datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M:%S"), err))
except Exception as err:
    logging.warning("{} - Failed to delete local file: {}".format(datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M:%S"), err))
```

Comment: thanks a million!  Your solution worked on Windows 10 for me too.  Why does it work?  Does it allow the MediaFileUpload object to be garbage collected, which closing all of its resources?

Answer (score 1):

I've tried it with one of my projects, and you can just add a return function of anything (i just used file id), and then after using `upload()`, just do `os.remove('somethingidk.jpg')`.

For example:

## Before:

main.py

```
                try:
                    SendFile('output.avi', 'output.avi', 'video/avi')
                except:
                    SendFile('output.avi', 'output.avi', 'video/avi')
```

---

file-uploader.py

```
def SendFile(file_path, file_name, mime):
    folder_id = ''
    file_metadata = {
    'name': file_name,
    'parents': [folder_id]}
    media = MediaFileUpload(file_path,
                        mimetype=mime)
    file = service.files().create(body=file_metadata,
                                    media_body=media,
                                    fields='id').execute()
    print("File ID: %s" % file.get('id'))
    os.remove('output.avi')
```

## After:

main.py

```
                try:
                    SendFile('output.avi', 'output.avi', 'video/avi')
                except:
                    SendFile('output.avi', 'output.avi', 'video/avi')

                os.remove('output.avi')
```

---

file-uploader.py

```
def SendFile(file_path, file_name, mime):
    folder_id = ''
    file_metadata = {
    'name': file_name,
    'parents': [folder_id]}
    media = MediaFileUpload(file_path,
                        mimetype=mime)
    file = service.files().create(body=file_metadata,
                                    media_body=media,
                                    fields='id').execute()
    print("File ID: %s" % file.get('id'))
    return file.get('id')
```

## Edit

### Or...

#### Just do this:

```
def SendFileIncomplete(file_path, file_name, mime):
    folder_id = ''
    file_metadata = {
    'name': file_name,
    'parents': [folder_id]}
    media = MediaFileUpload(file_path,
                        mimetype=mime)
    file = service.files().create(body=file_metadata,
                                    media_body=media,
                                    fields='id').execute()
    return ("File ID: %s" % file.get('id'))

def SendFile(file_path, file_name, mime):
    SendFileIncomplete(file_path, file_name, mime)
    os.remove(file_name)
```

What this is is just using a function inside of a function. You would then use `SendFile` when uploading.

Comment: I would love to use that, only that the calling function is an outside service - the uploading function is part of a Flask infrastructure, so it's run upon receiving a POST request to a certain url. So I can't have the calling function remove the file as it's not running on the same server. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this:

Using:

```
 gfile.content.close()
```

```
upload_file_list = ['photo1.jpg', 'photo2.jpg']
for upload_file in upload_file_list:
    gfile = drive.CreateFile({'parents': [{'id': 'Google folder ID'}]}) #add the folder ID here
    # Read file and set it as the content of this instance.
    gfile.SetContentFile(upload_file)
    gfile.Upload() # Upload the file
gfile.content.close() #close the file
```