# Cannot rename or move the file after downloading it from Google Drive using Drive API

Tags: python, google-drive-api

I'm trying to write a script that uploads an image to Google Drive and download the OCR version of the image as text file.

The script run through every image file in a given folder and does the above thing. The text file is first saved as "just-temp.txt" and after it has been successfully downloaded, the file should be renamed to the name of the image file with .txt extension. However, python is just throwing `PermissionError: [WinError 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process:` error.

This is the basic version of my code:

```
inputdir = r'D:\test (Screenshots)'

for dirpath, dirs, files in os.walk(inputdir):
    files = [file for file in files if file.endswith(('.png','.jpg','.jpeg'))]

    for count, file in enumerate(files, start=1):

        thefile = os.path.join(dirpath,file)
        txtfile = os.path.splitext(thefile)[0] + ".txt"

        txtfile_tmp_name = dirpath + '\\' + 'just-temp' + '.txt'

        if os.path.isfile(txtfile):
           print ('File already processed.')
        else:
          print ('Processing file ...')

# Drive api code to upload image and download text file.

          mime = 'application/vnd.google-apps.document'
          res = service.files().create(
              body={
                  'name': thefile,
                  'mimeType': mime
              },
              media_body=MediaFileUpload(thefile, mimetype=mime, resumable=True)
           ).execute()

           downloader = MediaIoBaseDownload(
               io.FileIO(txtfile_tmp_name, 'wb'),
               service.files().export_media(fileId=res['id'], mimeType="text/plain")
           )
           done = False
           while done is False:
               status, done = downloader.next_chunk()

           service.files().delete(fileId=res['id']).execute()

# To rename "just-temp.txt" to the image file name

           os.rename(txtfile_tmp_name, txtfile)

           print ('File successfully processed.' + thefile)
```

Python just keep showing me the above error and nothing after that `os.rename` command is executed.

I want to first name the text file as "just-temp.txt" so that if suddenly my internet goes off and the file isn't successfully downloaded, the file is re-processed the next time I run the script. But why is it showing error on a simple command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After spending much time on web searching for a similar question, I finally found a solution.

You need to set the variable used to store your `MediaFileUpload` object to None:

So only one extra line of code did it:

```
downloader = MediaIoBaseDownload(
               io.FileIO(txtfile_tmp_name, 'wb'),
               service.files().export_media(fileId=res['id'], mimeType="text/plain")
           )
           done = False
           while done is False:
               status, done = downloader.next_chunk()

           service.files().delete(fileId=res['id']).execute()

           downloader = None

           os.rename(txtfile_tmp_name, txtfile)
```

All thanks to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56621668):